# Admob testing ads not showing after a day that they did

Tags: android, admob

Hello I am new to using the admob ads and I am having a weird issue. I added the testing ads using the following link: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

The ads worked great last night. I opened my application tonight and for some reason the ads tab was gone, looking at the console I am getting the following error: I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Any ideas what could be happening? Thank you!

JAVA:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
           .addTestDevice("ID from device added removed for post")
            .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

GRADLE:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
}
```

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: @DanielK Thank you for your reply i have added my code on to my question, whats weird is that yesterday i sent the apk to a different device and it worked there? is there like a specific time you can use the test ads?

Comment: Okay try to delete the APK from the device you're having problems with & then push it again & see if that fixes it.

Comment: @DanielK I tried doing that multiple times, I even tried deleting the cache before installing the apk again, its weird because the night before was working. Would it have to anything with using the same apk on another device? since its testing the ads only work on one device?

Comment: It's possible but how would admob know that the APK is installed in two places at the same time? I would understand if you run them at the same time but if they are not, how would it know?

Comment: @DanielK thats true its a tricky one, and since its a test case this connection to Firbase shouldnt really matter should it? cause i get the I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful error in the log

Comment: @Daniel its been a little while but I tested the admob again and it came back on its own, im not sure what happened but thank you again for all you help!

Comment: Weird problem, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check The following process, It may be help you

- First Check Project level gradel, Do you have implemented class path like following, `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`
- After then check app level dependency like following    `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'`(as per latest library)
- After then apply plugin at bottom like following `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
- And then after check your App Id or Unit Id is correct which you set.
- Then check your layout where you declare your add, Does following namespace implemented or not `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
- And If you are using InterstitialAd then it require to add testing device Id like following way,

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                    .build();

This all Thing may be help you,

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added my code on the top, from what I am seen all these information is currently in place. I noticed that when i sent the apk file to another device the ads worked but still not on my phone, I wonder why? can i only use the test ads only for a limited time?

Comment: very strange but i tested my app and the ads came back and I am able to use it with no problem, it could of been a hichkup from the ad server. Thank you again for all your help!